# Delete records depending on field when compared to another table

Tags: sql, sas, proc-sql

I have a very basic knowledge of SQL but for the purpose of handling a large amount of data, I need to use it. Here's my issue:

I have two tables, as follows:

```
table1:
id    begin    end
100   1998     2013
101   1996     2009

table2:
id    date     price    qtt
100   1996     10       200
100   1999     12       200
101   1997     13       100
101   2013     14       100
```

What I need to do is to erase the lines which have `date` smaller than the `begin` field or `date` larger than `end` for each id. Meaning that for `id` 101, no records should have date before 1996 nor after 2009.

So my intended result is:

```
id    date     price    qtt
100   1999     12       200
101   1997     13       100
```

Efficiency is a concern, as I am doing this for a table with several million records. I have prepared a sqlfiddle with these tables so that it is easier for you.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/66f54f/1

I apologize if this question is too simple but after searching for three hours, I was unable to solve it myself. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I am unaware, quite frankly. I am accessing an academic database through SSH and then executing SAS scripts remotely, through which I use SQL. So, I am accessing SAS files through SQL. I do not know how to answer to your question, I do not know if in this question it still is applicable.

Comment: The "database" would be "proc-sql" or "sas".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is standard SQL syntax for what you want to do:

```
delete from table2
    where not exists (select 1
                      from table1
                      where table1.id = table2.id and
                            table2.date between table1."begin" and table1."end"
                     );
```

Do note that if an `id` exists in `table2` but not `table1`, then all rows for that `id` will be deleted.

This should be pretty efficient in most databases if you have an index on `table1(id, date)`.

Comment: Thank you for your rapid answer. Are you able to make this work in SQLFiddle? I wanted to test it as my "work environment" is not the most friendly (SQL in SAS, remotely executing SAS, printing tables, check results).

Comment: I applied your solution to my database and it worked! Thank you very much. I now need to add a `price` x `quantity` column (which is easy) and then to divide that column by the sum of that column for the records with the same `date`. This is not that easy. I am looking into sum over but it is still inconclusive...

Comment: @Bohemian . . . I think that using `between` with dates is dangerous for a few reasons.  With a "real" date, a time value can do unexpected things with "between".  In colloquial usage, many people think that "between" does not include the end points.  And, the OP already seems pretty confused between a "date" and a "year", as well as using reserved words as identifiers.

Comment: Sorry for the reserved words, it was my fault when creating the example. In fact, in the base examples it is start and ending rather than begin and end. Dates are also not years, I just simplified it. But your solution works, though I do not understand why table2."begin" rather than table1."begin"? It gave me errors in the output so I changed it and it worked.

Comment: Additionally, could you help me with the additional column I need in my data? I constructed a column with `price` times `qtt` but now I need to sum those over `date`. I have tried SUM(`variable`) OVER (PARTITION BY `date`) but it is not working. Still trying

Comment: I hear you, but... `between` is surely easier to read and understand (it sounds like English) than a mathematical expression. If someone can't understand what between means in SQL, I doubt expressing it otherwise will help. I think that learning the absolute basics of a language is a reasonable expectation, and 'between' falls into that category. Perhaps my penchant for brevity is colouring my viewpoint.

Comment: @jarspa . . . I was just confused about which table was which, which is why the aliases were backwards.  As for your other issue, you should ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
DELETE FROM A
FROM TABLE2 A
inner join table1 B
on A.id=B.id
and (A.[DATE] BETWEEN B.[BEGIN] AND B.[End])
```

Comment: Hello. Sorry, I have not tried your solution yet but thank you for your help.